# How to redirect with expressjs for a specific status?

Tags: ajax, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I'm doing a blog-app currently, and I'm struggling to find a way to redirect/send a specific status and then act accordingly.

For example, I have a function that saves data in mongodb using mongoose. Then if no errors occurred 200 status.

```
newArticle.save(function(err){
   if (err) throw err;
  else {
   res.sendStatus(200);
  }
});
```

I want to be able to "fetch" this status (I'm using react for my views and routes and superagent for my ajax request), and then do something, for example, If my article is successfully added then load a certain component on the page that will have an h1 saying : Great job on posting an article.

So this is the first part.

The second part is, for everything 404 or 500 errors I want express to redirect me from for example : myblog.com -> myblog.com/something and then with my react router simply render some basic 404 pages, I do not know how to do that, I'm searching a lot and couldn't find something...

And, since I lack knowledge in the HTTP basics like how server and client talk to each other, if you have any good article/books to recommend I'd like to know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first part. Depending on if you are using state or data library like flux or redux, if not, you can just have ajax response will have the HTTP status from your server. Using that, you can use setState to set a state property called something like `isArticleSaveSucessful`. Then simply render your success message component if that key is true.

Second part. For the better user experience which is I think what you intended, the url should still be what the user intended, ie, blog.com/bad-article-name but the page should render a 404. Very similar to above, when the API response comes back, setState accordingly, something like `articleNotFound`. Then in your render function, do an `if` check on the the state and if it is true, then render your error component.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks a lot for your answer, I got one more question, in my expressjs react blog app I'm using react-router as my router and i'm thinking that I can't monitor 404 pages with express js because react-router only manage my routes and therefor tell me if or if not a component is linked to router, I was wondering if there was a built in feature that throws a default component for an unknown route, I don't know if you see what I mean, sorry for my english

Comment: React-route does have the ability to show a default route that could be used to render a page not found with `path='*'`, but it doesn't work for what you are describing. It is only for when your route doesn't match a pattern. For your scenario, the blog url does match your routes but the specific blog entry is not found, this technically satisfied the react-router part of the job. The logic behind server routing is a different from client-side routing. This aside, showing a notFound component on your route is the more 'react' way to do it.